# Delete every sObject record assigned to a user without specifying sObject

Tags: apex, user, delete

As far as I know this is not possible but, is there a way we can delete all records related to a User (without specifying its sObject) from Apex?

Comment: this is a hard problem because you need in some cases to delete child objects first before the parents can be deleted (e.g. you can't delete an Account if it is parent to Order without deleting Orders first)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is not possible to Delete the record owned by any user without specifying the object.

So you can use the concept of [Mass Delete](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_massdelete.htm&type=5)

1. We strongly suggest you run a report to archive your information and export your data weekly. See [Export Backup Data from Salesforce.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_exportdata.htm&type=5)
2. From Setup, enter **Mass Delete Records** in the Quick Find box, then select Mass Delete Records and click the link for the type of record to delete.
3. Review the information that is deleted with the records.
4. Specify conditions that the selected items must match, for example, “Owner Last Name equals Ranjan.”
5. If you’re deleting accounts, specify whether you want to delete accounts with attached closed/won opportunities or attached opportunities owned by others
6. If you’re deleting products, select **Archive Products** if you also want to delete products that are on opportunities.
   This option:

   - Deletes products that are not on opportunities and moves them to the Recycle Bin.
   - Archives products that are on opportunities. These products are not moved to the Recycle Bin and cannot be recovered.

To delete only those products that are not on opportunities, do not select Archive Products. Selected products that are on opportunities remain checked after the deletion to indicate that they were not included in the deletion.

7. To find records that match, click **Search** and select the items you want to delete. To select all currently displayed items, check the box in the column header.
8. To permanently delete records, select **Permanently delete the selected records**.

**Note** :- Selecting this option prevents you from recovering the selected records from the Recycle Bin.

9. Click **Delete**.
   If you did not select P**ermanently delete the selected records**, deleted items are moved to the Recycle Bin.